# Humidity in a shower with a microcement floor

Tags: shower, flooring, humidity

I made a decision that is giving me several problems: I decided to put a microcement floor in my house.

One of the dirtiest problems is in the shower. The micro-cement around the drain gets wet when I have a shower.

As you can see in the image, I tried to put some SikaFlex in between the drain and the floor, but it doesn't work.

Do you have any clue about what should I do?

[image: humidity in microcement]

Comment: Welcome to DIYSE. I don't understand. Wouldn't you expect a shower floor to get wet? What does "dirtiest" mean?

Comment: mmm... I am refering to the microcement. It changes its colour. Inside.

Comment: Never heard of microcement so i found the website. It is stated there that microcement surface is **"water-repellent on the visible surface. It is not, however, a waterproofing element, so it is necessary that the base on which it is applied is perfectly dry and be sure that moisture does not appear in the future."**  I suspect that area around the drain was not water proofed before the drain was installed and i do not know  if it can be as it is stated that the "surface is water-repellent" not the base. **Have you contacted the manufacturer?**